# C++ count the number of words from standard input

Tags: c++, distance, istream-iterator

I saw a piece of C++ code to count the number of words inputted from standard input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto ss {
        istream_iterator<string>{cin}
    };
    cout << distance(ss, {}) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have several questions:

1. What's the type of `auto ss`?
2. What does `distance(ss, {})` do? Why does it calculate the number of words?

My guess is:

1. `istream_iterator<string>{cin}` converts the standard input into the `istream_iterator` type, automatically separated by space (why?). Thus `ss` looks like a `container` with all words as its elements;
2. `distance(ss, {})` calculates the distance between the 1st element and the empty (thus outside of the last, but why?) element.

Can someone help me to go through my guess on this fantastic short piece of code?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator.

Comment: `auto ss {istream_iterator<string>{cin}};` is just a fancy way of saying `istream_iterator<string> ss(cin);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto ss` deduces `ss` to be [`std::istream_iterator<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), because that is what the full statement is constructing and assigning to `ss`.

`istream_iterator` uses the specified `istream`'s [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) to read formatted input of the specified type, where `operator>>` reads input delimited by whitespace, including space characters, line breaks, etc.  So, in this case, `istream_iterator<string>` is reading [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) values from [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) one whitespace-delimited word at a time.

`istream_iterator` is an input iterator, and a default-constructed `istream_iterator` denotes an *end-of-stream* iterator.  When `istream_iterator` stops reading (EOF is reached, bad input is entered, etc), its value becomes equal to the *end-of-stream* iterator.

[`std::distance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) returns the number of elements in a range denoted by a pair of iterators.  For a non-random input iterator, like `istream_iterator`, `std::distance()` iterates the range one element at a time via the iterator's `operator++`, counting the number of times it incremented the iterator, until the target iterator is reached. So, in this case, [`istream_iterator::operator++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator_arith) internally reads a value from its `istream`, thus `std::distance()` effectively returns how many words are successfully read from `std::cin` until *end-of-stream* is reached.

So, the code you have shown is roughly just an algorithmic way of writing the following equivalent loop:

```cpp
int main() {
    string s;
    size_t count = 0;
    while (cin >> s) {
        ++count;
    }
    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Remy for your detailed explanation! Just one more question on `std::distance()`: why do we need to provide an empty `{}` in `distance(ss, {})`? By https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance, the 2nd input should be `InputIt last` which has the same type that the 1st input `InputIt first`. How do we make sure `{}` is of the same type as `ss` then?

Answer (score 1):

1. `ss` has type `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`.
2. `std::distance(ss, {})` computes the number of items between the first whitespace-delimited token in std::cin to the end of cin, effectively returning the number of whitespace-delimited tokens in std::cin.  This is due to the way `std::istream::operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)` functions (the second parameter is not actually an `std::string`, but I'm trying to keep this short).  The default constructor for a `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` returns the end of any `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`.

The cutting of the contents of std::cin is actually done lazily when computing the distance.

That is indeed an interesting piece of code.